# Finding a computation error about automorphisms of elliptic curves over finite fields with characteristic $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I am trying to understand a computation of the paper [Twists of Elliptic Curves by Kronberg, Soomro and Top](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02893.pdf).

Let $E,E'$ be a elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_3$ given by
$$
E: \quad y^2 = x^3 - x
$$
and
$$
E': \quad y^2 = x^3 + x.
$$

Further assume that $K = \mathbb{F}_q$ be an extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ of odd degree.

We consider the automorphism $\Psi_{u,r}: E \to E$ given by $\Psi_{u,r}(x,y) = (u^2 x + r, u^3 y)$ (where $u^4=1$ and $r \in \mathbb{F}_3$).

In the proof of Proposition 2.1. in the paper, it is said that for $\psi: E \to E'$, $(x,y) \mapsto (ix,-iy)$ (with $i^2 = -1$), we have $\left( \operatorname{Fr}(\psi) \right)^{-1} \circ
\psi = \Psi_{i,0}$ (where $Fr$ is the field automorphism raising any element to its qth power, according to the paper). **Now I am trying to verify this equality**.

Since $\psi(x,y) = (ix,-iy)$, I concluded $\operatorname{Fr}(\psi)(x,y) = (i^q x, (-i)^q y) = (-ix, iy)$ (since $K/\mathbb{F}_3$ is odd) and therefore $\left( \operatorname{Fr}(\psi) \right)^{-1}(x,y) = (ix,-iy)$. This would give $\left( \operatorname{Fr}(\psi) \right)^{-1} \circ \psi (x,y) = (-x,-y)$. However, it is $\Psi_{i,0}(x,y) = (-x,-iy)$, so I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Could you help me finding my error?

Comment: I don't think $\psi$ sends $E$ to $E'$:  if $y^2 = x^3 - x$, then $(-iy)^2 = -y^2 = -(x^3 - x) \neq -i(x^3 - x) = (ix)^3 + (ix)$.

Comment: Perhaps it should be $(x, y) \mapsto (ix, (1+i)y)$?

Comment: I agree with Ravi Fernando. We have $(ix)^3+(ix)=-i(x^3-x)$, so you need to multiply $y$ with a square root of $-i$ to make the equations click. $\zeta_8=1+i$ is one such. Because $[K:\Bbb{F}_3]$ is odd, $q\equiv 3\pmod 8$, so $\zeta_8^q=\zeta_8^3=-i\zeta_8$.